# EmberJS route design for multi-step workflow

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to understand the best way to design a multi-step workflow;

So I have the following possibilities;

```
Step 1 (list) > Step 2a (review screen a) > Step3 (confirm screen)

Step 1 (list) > Step 2b (review screen b) > Step3 (confirm screen)
```

At each step, I call an API and based on the response, I make a decision.
It is possible that user moves from Step 1 directly to Step 3 (based on API response)

OR it is also possible to have

```
Step 1 (list) > Step 2a (review screen a) > Step 2b (review screen b) > Step3 (confirm screen)
```

What is the best way to design the routes considering the above ?
I mean in terms of nested routes, dynamic segments, folder structure for route objects, etc ?

Comment: Please elaborate a little bit more on what actually you are trying to implement. I suggest that with ember you don't look into routes much. Yes of course every app should be about routes, but... Ember brings components and soon to bring routable components. the `{{component}}` helper i.e. gives you ability to put in template any component you want depending on previous choices made by user. And of course the `transitionTo('route')` method allows you to jump from route to route programmatically - http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_transitionTo .

Answer (score 0):

One option is to put Steps 2a, 2b and 3 directly inside Step 1's route and then use transitionTo()to move between the routes as @canufeel mentioned